# What would be the best method to make a packaged graphic representation of data from excel?

Tags: flash, html, excel, spreadsheet

A client is looking for methods for data visualisation based off of massive Excel files. There are a few stipulations. In the past the finished product was produced in flash. Then it has been emailed to the client in a zip secured by a password. The flash file itself allows for structured manipulation of the data. Nothing more than parsing the data in a few different ways. The client has asked if there are other options out there for accomplishing this in a more efficent way. I guess I am just trolling for suggestions at this point. Nothing too complex. I have also been tasked with researching the viability of switching to HTML 5 as a delivery method. I am unsure at this point if the client wants to incorporate a format that allows for real time updating via a server and web presence. For now I believe it is just creating graphs from the data and sending it along.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for the length of the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the dataset isn't so large that excel would have troubles calculating on it. 
Also, assuming you are using a recent excel version (that has slicers, etc)
(if those assumption are false disregard suggestion, I made them as it seems this organization is pretty tech savvy)

Why not create an excel dashboard worksheet that uses slicers and pivot charts as well as creating summary statistics with formulas like countif(s), sumif(s), averageif(s) etc. This way you can provide parameter cells, sliders, slicers, etc to adjust the visualizations

Then just password protect the workbook. you can even protect all the sheets you dont want to be edited with a separate password